# Windows server 2012/6 Limit copying size

Tags: windows

we need to add a limit for pasting to SMB Folder from Windows Server 2012. Is any way, users within MS Server to have quota/limiter once pasting files to SMB share? The share is mounted at Windows Server.

Thank you

Comment: For all of the files they own?

Comment: Yes for all files!

Comment: check the question I just linked

Comment: the question is not how to limit total stored size per user but to limit users to paste files larger than X GB

Comment: So, not for all of their files - but for each individual file?

Comment: With such concept yes, each individual file

Answer (score 0):

There is no "File Size per User" limit in windows. The FSRM (File Server Resource manager) can set quotas per disk and per folder (per user or group), but not a single Max-File-Size thing.